# How to troubleshoot NIS binding problems on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, directory-utility

I am trying to setup NIS on OS X 10.8 but it fails for some reasons.

I tried to add the NIS domain using the Directory Utility.app but when I go to Directory Editor tab and select my NIS node, I do get an error:

`Connection failed to node '/NIS/uk.example.com' (2100)`

**On OS X 10.8 machine**

- `uk.example.com` is the domainname (does *not* solve in DNS)
- `nis2.uk.example.com` is the ypbind server (does solve in DNS)
- I am already on corporate LAN and I can ping nis2.uk.example.com
- `domainname` returns uk.example.com
- `ypbind -d` prints 'ypbind: returned from 10.80.16.129 about uk.example.com' but it does not return, I need to press Ctrl-C.

`dhcp-3-130:~ sorins$ rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100007    2   udp    845  ypbind
    100007    2   tcp   1009  ypbind`

dhcp-3-130:~ sorins$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: /Network/Servers updated
automount: no unmounts

ypwhich
nis2.uk.example.com

** On a reference Ubuntu, in the same LAN, where NIS works **

```
ypbind -d
31213: parsing config file
31213: Trying entry: domain uk.example.com server 10.80.16.129
31213: parsed domain 'uk.example.com' server '10.80.16.129'
31213: add_server() domain: uk.example.com, host: 10.80.16.129, slot: 0
31213: [Welcome to ypbind-mt, version 1.20.1]
```

So Ubuntu works, but on OS X it doesn't. **Why?**

Comment: If you use `ypset` and `ypbind` from the command line, it will often give you a more actionable message than trying to figure out the GUI from the console logs. Can we presume you've made sure the host is reachable over the ports NIS uses?

Comment: @bmike it gives me only what I already pasted and this is happening only if I call it with `-d` parameter. BTW, The Mac is already configured to be part of an Active Directory, but this should not interfere with this.

Comment: Hmm - you wouldn't think that an AD binding would change the error message or take precedent when trying to establish a NIS binding. Hope someone has more of an idea?

Comment: I removed the AD completely from the setup, just to be sure. Still I do get the same behaviour.

Comment: What version/edition of ypserver are you connecting to? I hit this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=781880

Answer (score 1):

Since NIS is a third party product - you should be able to follow any of the great troubleshooting guides on the internet and make headway to determine if this is a client or server issue.

My gold standard for a NIS guide is from IBM:

- [Troubleshooting NIS-Related Problems](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.nisplus/doc/nisplus/trbl_nis.htm)

From what you have posted in the question edits - it appears that `ypwhich` would be the next item to check to ensure the client OS is configured properly. If not, the network troubleshooting or a manual `ypset` may be needed. If to, you could use `ypcat` to see that the command line can call some of the maps you care to configure on the client side (hosts for example).